# Entity Framework query improved

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to make an android synchronization between client and ASP.NET MVC server. The logic is simple, my next method receives a data dictionary, where key = idGroup and value = LastMessageIdKnown, in the end I should get the next messages for each group what Id is higher than the LastMessageIdKnown (the value of my dictionary).

Right now I am iterating the map, for each key I do a query to my SQL database but this is inefficient, if I got N keys you can imagine what implying.

This is my current method

```
public Dictionary<int, List<Messages>> SynchronizedChatMessages(Dictionary<int, int> data)
{
    Dictionary<int, List<Messages>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<Messages>>();


    foreach(int item in data.Keys){
        var idMessage= data[item];
        var listMessages= _context.Messages.Where(x => x.Grupo_ID == item && x.ID > idMessage).ToList();
        result.Add(item,listMessages);
    }
    return result;
}
```

How can I improve this query to get all what I need in an only and optimal way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt that uses `Predicate`s to make it so that there is only one `Where` against the whole collection of messages.

Note that I mocked this up without a database, so I am passing a List into the `SynchronizedChatMessages` function, whereas you have the context available.

What remains to be proven is that this way of doing things only generates one query to the database (since I did it in objects only). The whole program is further, below, but first, just the function showing use of predicates to achieve firing the `Where` only once.

```
public static Dictionary<int, List<Message>> SynchronizedChatMessages(List<Message> messages, Dictionary<int, int> data)
{
    List<Predicate<Message>> predList = new List<Predicate<Message>>();
    //Built of list of indivIdual predicates
    foreach (var x in data)
    {
        var IdMessage = x.Key;
        var lastMessageId = x.Value;

        Predicate<Message> pred = m => m.IdGroup.Id == IdMessage && m.Id > lastMessageId;
        predList.Add(pred);
    }

    //compose the predicates
    Predicate<Message> compositePredicate = m =>
    {
        bool ret = false;
        foreach (var pred in predList)
        {
            //If any of the predicates is true, the composite predicate is true (OR)
            if (pred.Invoke(m) == true) { ret = true; break; }
        }
        return ret;
    };

    //do the query
    var messagesFound = messages.Where(m => compositePredicate.Invoke(m)).ToList();

    //get the individual distinct IdGroupIds
    var IdGroupIds = messagesFound.Select(x => x.IdGroup.Id).ToList().Distinct().ToList();

    //Create dictionary to return
    Dictionary<int, List<Message>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<Message>>();
    foreach (int i in IdGroupIds)
    {
        result.Add(i, messagesFound.Where(m => m.IdGroup.Id == i).ToList());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Here is the whole thing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
public class Program
{
    public class Message
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public IdGroup IdGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class IdGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, List<Message>> SynchronizedChatMessages(List<Message> messages, Dictionary<int, int> data)
    {
        List<Predicate<Message>> predList = new List<Predicate<Message>>();
        //Built of list of indivIdual predicates
        foreach (var x in data)
        {
            var IdMessage = x.Key;
            var lastMessageId = x.Value;

            Predicate<Message> pred = m => m.IdGroup.Id == IdMessage && m.Id > lastMessageId;
            predList.Add(pred);
        }

        //compose the predicates
        Predicate<Message> compositePredicate = m =>
        {
            bool ret = false;
            foreach (var pred in predList)
            {
                //If any of the predicates is true, the composite predicate is true (OR)
                if (pred.Invoke(m) == true) { ret = true; break; }
            }
            return ret;
        };

        //do the query
        var messagesFound = messages.Where(m => compositePredicate.Invoke(m)).ToList();

        //get the individual distinct IdGroupIds
        var IdGroupIds = messagesFound.Select(x => x.IdGroup.Id).ToList().Distinct().ToList();

        //Create dictionary to return
        Dictionary<int, List<Message>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<Message>>();
        foreach (int i in IdGroupIds)
        {
            result.Add(i, messagesFound.Where(m => m.IdGroup.Id == i).ToList());
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item1 = new IdGroup { Id = 2, Messages = new List<Message>() };
        var item2 = new IdGroup { Id = 45, Messages = new List<Message>() };
        var item3 = new IdGroup { Id = 36, Messages = new List<Message>() };
        var item4 = new IdGroup { Id = 8, Messages = new List<Message>() };

        var message1 = new Message { Id = 3, IdGroup = item1 };
        var message2 = new Message { Id = 7, IdGroup = item1 };
        var message3 = new Message { Id = 9, IdGroup = item1 };
        item1.Messages.Add(message1);
        item1.Messages.Add(message2);
        item1.Messages.Add(message3);

        var message4 = new Message { Id = 4, IdGroup = item2 };
        var message5 = new Message { Id = 10, IdGroup = item2 };
        var message6 = new Message { Id = 76, IdGroup = item2 }; 
        item2.Messages.Add(message4);
        item2.Messages.Add(message5);
        item2.Messages.Add(message6);

        var message7 = new Message { Id = 6, IdGroup = item3 };
        var message8 = new Message { Id = 32, IdGroup = item3 };
        item3.Messages.Add(message7);
        item3.Messages.Add(message8);

        var message9 = new Message { Id = 11, IdGroup = item4 };
        var message10 = new Message { Id = 16, IdGroup = item4 };
        var message11 = new Message { Id = 19, IdGroup = item4 };
        var message12 = new Message { Id = 77, IdGroup = item4 }; 
        item4.Messages.Add(message9);
        item4.Messages.Add(message10);
        item4.Messages.Add(message11);
        item4.Messages.Add(message12);

        List<IdGroup> items = new List<IdGroup> { item1, item2, item3, item4 };
        List<Message> messages = new List<Message> { message1, message2, message3, message4, message5, message6,message7, message8, message9, message10, message11, message12};
        Dictionary<int, int> lastMessagesPerItem = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 2, 3 }, { 45, 10 }, { 36, 6 }, { 8, 11 } };

        var result = SynchronizedChatMessages(messages, lastMessagesPerItem);

        var discard = Console.ReadKey();                     

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but seem that the method Invoke doesnt work on the DataBase context. I 've read some info about this case, reading in StackOferflow and in others forum the users talks about a nuget named "LinqKit". I installed this nuget but there is incompatibility bewteen ensambled entityframework 6. I means your solution is good and works in normal collection, but doesn't work if you use in a data base context.

Comment: The error is "the class Message does not support the method "Invoke" (NotSupportedException)

Comment: Thanks for the followup, @AbelMorgan, sorry it didn't work in a database context.

Comment: @AbelMorgan: maybe you can adapt the predicate approach to look like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13181215/49251, so that it works in a database context.

Comment: And after you accepted, I also find this, which explains why the expression approach is necessary when it's Linq to SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618035/49251.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would be nice if this would work, but I doubt it that can be translated to a SQL statement in one go:

```
var toInsert = 
     from msg in _context.Messages
     group msg by msg.Grupo_ID into g
     where data.Keys.Contains(g.Key)
     select new {
         Item = g.Key,
         Messages = g.Where(x => x.ID > data[g.Key])
     };
```

I don't think the second `Where` clause `x => x.ID > data[g.Key]` can be translated.

So you may need to do this in two passes, like this:

```
// This is a single SQL query.
var groups = 
     from msg in _context.Messages
     group msg by msg.Grupo_ID into g
     where data.Keys.Contains(g.Key)
     select new {
         Item = g.Key,
         // ordering helps us when we do the in-memory part.
         Messages = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).ToList()
     };

// This iterates the result set in memory
foreach (var g in groups)
    result.Add(
        g.Item, 
        // input is ordered, we stop when an item is <= data[g.Item].
        g.Messages.TakeWhile(m => m.ID > data[g.Item]).ToList())
```

Comment: This still runs in one pass, because `groups` is an `IQueryable`. So in fact it wouldn't run. However if you add `groups.AsEnumerable()` I doubt whether grabbing all messages from the database (for each group) will be more efficient than doing a query per group.

Comment: @GertArnold the `.ToList()` ensures that `Messages` in the second `groups` query is not lazily evaluated. Given the fact that it would return a full set of `Messages` for each matching group, from which a selection is made in memory in the `foreach`, if the amount of messages is very large, it may indeed become less efficient than performing repeated queries in a loop, but that would then be due to the size of the result set that needs in-memory filtering.

Comment: It would all run as one statement. The `ToList()` is redundant because at the moment `groups` is actually executed, lazy loading wouldn't occur anyway (besides, what entity would they be loaded into?). As for efficiency, I guess this is one of those questions only the OP can answer.