# how to use predicate into a join statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linqkit

I am trying to allow my users to construct their own queries. I found this code which seems to solve this problem:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T1>();

if (a != "")
    predicado = predicado.And(e1 => e1.field1.Contains(a));

if (b!= "")
    predicado = predicado.And(e1 => e1.field2.Contains(b));

var TestQuery = db.T1.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
```

These are my model classes:

```
public partial class T1
{
    public long id_t1 { get; set; }

    public string field1 { get; set; }

    public string field2 { get; set; }
}

public partial class T1
{
    public long id_t2 { get; set; }

    public string field1 { get; set; }

    public string field2 { get; set; }
}
```

But i need a way to use the `PredicateBuilder` in a join statement like this one:

```
var query = from f in db.T1
    where (f.T1field1.Equals("something") && f.T1field2.Equals("something"))
    join m in db.T2 on f.T1field1 equals m.T2field1
    where (m.T2fiel1 != null && m.T2field2 != null )
    select m;
```

Comment: ups when i say T2field1 i am talking about  the  column field1 in the table T2

Comment: and the same goes for the T1field1

Comment: In order for this to work with Linq to Sql (and Linq with EF also needs to go to Sql in the end), your predicates have to be available in expressions: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618035/49251 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/29871197/49251.

Comment: eureka , this way work for me:

Comment: 'var query = from f in db.T1'
   ' where (f.T1field1.Equals("something") && f.T1field2.Equals("something"))
    join m in db.T2 on f.T1field1 equals m.T2field1
    where (m.T2fiel1 != null && m.T2field2 != null )
    select m;

Comment: sorry is this way var query = from f in db.T1.AsExpandable().Where (predicado)
    join m in db.T2 on f.T1field1 equals m.T2field1.AsExpendable().Where(predicado) 
   
    select m;

Comment: and the predicado most be like this

Comment: 'var predicado = PredicateBuilder.True<T1>();'

'if (a != "")'

    'predicado = predicado.And(e1 => e1.field1.Contains(a));'